# How do i fix the problem with my calculate() function?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

I had recently started python and I have been learning the tkinter module. I decided to take up the task of making a gui calculator, but my problem is that my equal to button is not working at all. Can you please help me with it?

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Calculator")
window.geometry("550x425")
window.iconbitmap("Dtafalonso-Android-Lollipop-Calculator.ico")

#functions
def button(parent,text,font,bg,width, pad=1):
    btn = Button(parent, text=text, font=font, bg=bg, width=width, height=2, relief=FLAT, bd=0, padx=pad)
    return btn

#Globals
full_stop = 1
left_bracket=0

#number functions

def zero(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get()+ "0")
def one(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get()+ "1")
def two(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get()+ "2")
def three(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get()+ "3")
def four(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get()+ "4")
def five(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get()+ "5")
def six(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get()+ "6")
def seven(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get()+ "7")
def eight(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get()+ "8")
def nine(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get()+ "9")

def add():
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 30 and not expression.get().endswith("."):
        if expression.get().endswith("+"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "-")
        elif expression.get().endswith("-"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "+")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "+")
        elif expression.get().endswith("÷"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "+")
        else:
            expression.set(expression.get() + "+")
        full_stop = 1

def subtract():
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 30 and not expression.get().endswith("."):
        if expression.get().endswith("+"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "-")
        elif expression.get().endswith("-"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "-")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "-")
        elif expression.get().endswith("÷"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "-")
        else:
            expression.set(expression.get() + "-")
        full_stop = 1

def multiply():
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 30 and not expression.get().endswith("."):
        if expression.get().endswith("+"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "-")
        elif expression.get().endswith("-"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("÷"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x")
        else:
            expression.set(expression.get() + "x")
        full_stop = 1

def divide():
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 30 and not expression.get().endswith("."):
        if expression.get().endswith("+"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "-")
        elif expression.get().endswith("-"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "÷")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "÷")
        elif expression.get().endswith("÷"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "÷")
        else:
            expression.set(expression.get() + "÷")
        full_stop = 1

def point():
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 20 and full_stop == 1:
        if not expression.get().endswith(("+","-","x","÷","(",")")):
            expression.set(expression.get()+".")
            full_stop = 0

def left():
    global left_bracket
    if expression.get() =="0":
        expression.set("(")
    else:
        expression.set(expression.get() + "(")
    left_bracket += 1

def right():
    global left_bracket
    if left_bracket != 0 and not expression.get() == "0":
        expression.set(expression.get() + ")")
        left_bracket -= 1

def reverse():
    if not expression.get().startswith("-") and not expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set("-" + expression.get())
    elif expression.get().startswith("-"):
        expression.set(expression.get()[1:])

def delete():
    expression.set(expression.get()[:-1])
    if expression.get() == "":
        expression.set("0")

def reset():
    global for_calc
    expression.set("0")
    for_calc = None
    calculatereal.set("")

def calculate():
    try:
        res = str(eval(expression))
        calculatereal.set(res)
        
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        calculatereal.set("Error")

    expression.set("0")

#Variables 0_0
expression = StringVar(window,"0")
calculatereal = StringVar(window)

#Main entry box (Real) 0_0
expression_display = Entry(window, textvariable=expression, justify=RIGHT, selectbackground="#727478", selectforeground="#000000", readonlybackground="#D9D9D9", relief=FLAT, bd=0, state="readonly", font="Verdana 18 bold")
expression_display.pack(pady=5, anchor=N, padx=2, fill=X)

calculatereal_lbl = Label(window, textvariable=calculatereal, anchor=E, bg="#D9D9D9", relief=FLAT, bd=0, font="Verdana 18 bold")
calculatereal_lbl.pack(pady=5, anchor=N, padx=6, fill=X)

#SUS AMONGUS BUTTONS

#frame1
frame1= Frame(window, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame1, "CE", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.config(command=reset)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame1, "±", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=reverse)

btn = button(frame1, "C", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.config(command=delete)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame1, "÷", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=divide)

frame1.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)

#frame2
frame2= Frame(window, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame2, "7", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=seven)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame2, "8", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=eight)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame2, "9", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=nine)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame2, "×", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=multiply)

frame2.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)


#frame3
frame3= Frame(window, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame3, "4", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=four)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame3, "5", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=five)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame3, "6", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=six)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame3, "-", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=subtract)

frame3.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)


#frame4
frame4= Frame(window, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame4, "1", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=one)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame4, "2", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=two)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame4, "3", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=three)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame4, "+", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=add)

frame4.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)


#frame5
frame5= Frame(window, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame5, "(", "Verdana 15", "#EDEDED",4, pad=4)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=left)

btn = button(frame5, ")", "Verdana 15", "#EDEDED",4, pad=4)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=right)

btn = button(frame5, "0", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=zero)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame5, ".", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=point)

btn = button(frame5, "=", "Verdana 15", "#63bf76",10)
btn.config(command=calculate)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

frame5.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)

#Key binds
window.bind("0",zero)
window.bind("1",one)
window.bind("2",two)
window.bind("3",three)
window.bind("4",four)
window.bind("5",five)
window.bind("6",six)
window.bind("7",seven)
window.bind("8",eight)
window.bind("9",nine)

window.mainloop()
```

The calculate function, when executed showed that there was a type error:

> TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Also pls let me know if there are any other errors
^_^

Comment: It seems like `StringVar` is a class, not a string, byte or code object.

Comment: "expression" is a StringVar object. You must get the contained string for evaluation like you did in many other places of your code.

Comment: @MichaelButscher how do you exactl do that? Im a bit new to stringvar and im not completely clear about it

Comment: You did it multiple dozen times in the code and there is at least some [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#coupling-widget-variables) about StringVar et al.

Answer (score 0):

Your main error is that you use `expression` instead of `expression.get()` inside `calculate`.

You need to change some of your math symbols to conform to python math syntax:

- `'/'` instead of `'÷'`
- `'*'` instead of `'x'`

You may want to change `eval` to `ast.literal_eval` as well (low chance of bad wrong input currently) but using `eval` is principally frowned upon due to bad things that could happen.

```
def calculate():
    try:        
        # use expression.get() instead of expression
        # could be improved by using `ast.literal_eval` 

        # also needed:
        # replacing math sýmbols in expression to python math symbols 
        res = str(eval(expression.get().replace("x","*").replace("÷","/")))
        calculatereal.set(res)
        
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        calculatereal.set("Error")

    expression.set("0")
```

---

You have LOTs of repetitions in your code you need to replace by using functions - as well as edgecases - currently something like `999.99 + ()()()` is possible.

See my changes that replaces `one`...`nine`, `math_operation` for `sum` etc. as well as for keybindings on the window level. I started the fixing for you:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Calculator")
window.geometry("550x425") 

#functions
def button(parent,text,font,bg,width, pad=1):
    btn = Button(parent, text=text, font=font, bg=bg, 
                 width=width, height=2, relief=FLAT, bd=0, padx=pad)
    return btn

#Globals
full_stop = 1
left_bracket=0

#number functions


def too_long(text):
    # could pop up a message here
    # if you want a 50 wide one, change this in ONE place not all over
    return len(text) >= 30

def number(value, event = ""):
    """Your number functions did all the same things, just with
    some other numerical value - so get rid of single functions
    and call this one parametrised using a lambda (using either 
    a hardcoded integer:         lambda: number(42)
    or the key pressed event:    lambda e:  number(e.char)"""

    # cache the result instead of requerying
    expr = expression.get() 

    # change logic to get out if too long, else do stuff
    if too_long(expr):
        return

    elif expr == "0": # simpler test for exactly "0" and of len() 1
        expr = ""

    expr += str(value)
    expression.set(expr)

def math_operation (op):
    """Your math ops did also the same thing, just with a different
    operator. DRY == Don't Repeat Yourself - use funcs/lambda"""
    global full_stop
    # cache the result instead of requerying
    expr = expression.get()

    # I would use "+-x÷." further down and remove the "." here
    if too_long(expr) or expr[-1] == ".":
        return

    if expr[-1] in "+-x÷":
        expr = expr[:-1] + op
    else:
        expr += op
    
    full_stop = 1
    expression.set(expr)

def add():       math_operation("+")
def subtract():  math_operation("-")
def multiply():  math_operation("x")
def divide():    math_operation("÷")

def point():
    global full_stop
    expr = expression.get()
    if len(expr) < 20 and full_stop == 1:
        if not expr.endswith(("+","-","x","÷","(",")")):
            expression.set(expr + ".")
            full_stop = 0

def left():
    global left_bracket
    expr = expression.get()
    
    if expr == "0":
        expr = "("
    else:
        expr += "("
    expression.set(expr)
    left_bracket += 1

def right():
    # right and left needs fixing to avoid 888 + ()()() etc 
    global left_bracket
    expr = expression.get()
    # most probably expression is at least "("  from left()
    # ... don't get why this is done
    if left_bracket != 0 and not expr == "0": 
        expression.set(expr + ")")
        left_bracket -= 1

def reverse():
    expr = expression.get()
    if not expr[0] in "-0" and len(expr) < 30:
        expression.set("-" + expr[1:])
    elif expr.startswith("-"):
        expression.set(expr[1:])

def delete():
    expr = expression.get()
    expression.set(expr[:-1] or "0") # "" == falsy "0" will be used

def reset():
    global for_calc
    expression.set("0")
    for_calc = None
    calculatereal.set("")

def calculate():
    try:        
        # use `ast.literal_eval` 
        # replace some sýmbols to conform to math symbols 
        # used in python for eval
        res = str(eval(expression.get().replace("x","*").replace("÷","/")))
        calculatereal.set(res)
        
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        calculatereal.set("Error")

    expression.set("0")


#Variables 0_0
expression = StringVar(window,"0")
calculatereal = StringVar(window)

#Main entry box (Real) 0_0
expression_display = Entry(window, textvariable=expression, justify=RIGHT, 
                           selectbackground="#727478",
                           selectforeground="#000000", 
                           readonlybackground="#D9D9D9", 
                           relief=FLAT, bd=0, state="readonly",
                           font="Verdana 18 bold")
expression_display.pack(pady=5, anchor=N, padx=2, fill=X)

calculatereal_lbl = Label(window, textvariable=calculatereal, 
                          anchor=E, bg="#D9D9D9", relief=FLAT, 
                          bd=0, font="Verdana 18 bold")
calculatereal_lbl.pack(pady=5, anchor=N, padx=6, fill=X)

#SUS AMONGUS BUTTONS

# You can streamline this whole buildup with loops and smaller
# functions as well - happy coding if you want to try ;o)

# the "number" keys use a lambda wich is a way to create an inlined
# function that is callable - the lambda I use uses no parameter
# but calls the function with a hardcoded one
#   my_func = lambda x: x+x
#   my_func(42) # --> returns 84
#   my_other = lambda:  42
#   my_other() # --> returns 42

#frame1
frame1= Frame(window, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame1, "CE", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.config(command=reset)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame1, "±", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=reverse)

btn = button(frame1, "C", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.config(command=delete)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame1, "÷", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=divide)

frame1.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)

#frame2
frame2= Frame(window, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame2, "7", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=lambda: number(7))
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame2, "8", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=lambda: number(8))
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame2, "9", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=lambda: number(9))
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame2, "×", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=multiply)

frame2.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)


#frame3
frame3= Frame(window, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame3, "4", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=lambda: number(4))
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame3, "5", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=lambda: number(5))
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame3, "6", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=lambda: number(6))
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame3, "-", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=subtract)

frame3.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)


#frame4
frame4= Frame(window, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame4, "1", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=lambda: number(1))
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame4, "2", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=lambda: number(2))
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame4, "3", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=lambda: number(3))
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame4, "+", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=add)

frame4.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)


#frame5
frame5= Frame(window, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame5, "(", "Verdana 15", "#EDEDED",4, pad=4)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=left)

btn = button(frame5, ")", "Verdana 15", "#EDEDED",4, pad=4)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=right)

btn = button(frame5, "0", "Verdana 15", "#FFFFFF",10)
btn.config(command=lambda: number(0))
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame5, ".", "Verdana 15", "#EEEEEE",10)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)
btn.config(command=point)

btn = button(frame5, "=", "Verdana 15", "#63bf76",10)
btn.config(command=calculate)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

frame5.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)

# Key binds - we use the "char" value of the keypressed event 
# "e" and provide that instead of hardcoding the value - using
# a loop makes it shorter as well
for num in range(10):
    window.bind(str(num),lambda e: number(e.char))

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the help! Now I understood all my errors